# TCL: tcl command execute by variable

Tags: variables, command, tcl

I am a beginner with tcl.
I am trying to use primetime execute command, but it can't accept variable.
For example:

```
set var "get_timing_paths -rise_from A -rise_to B"
set path0001 [$var]
```

But it doesn't work.
The things I want to do is

```
set path0001 [get_timing_paths -rise_from A -rise_to B]
```

but I need to seperate it.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: sorry, I am not good at this website.

Comment: set var "get_timing_paths -rise_from A -rise_to B"

Comment: set path0001 [$var]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Tcl/Tk 8.5 or newer, it'd be better to use the list expansion operator `{*}` instead of `eval`:

```
set var "get_timing_paths -rise_from A -rise_to B"
set path0001 [{*}$var]
```

It's a bit faster and safer.

Comment: It's quite a lot faster. Possibly hugely so if you build the command to run with `list`.

Comment: I was using exec. So, I used it like this:
set TTY "| tee /dev/tty"
if [catch {exec sh s.sh {*}$TTY} result] { puts "Caught"}

Answer (score 0):

Just add `eval` while calling the command.

```
set path0001 [eval $var]
```

**Reference :** [eval](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/eval.htm)